# How to store response in variable in ROBOT framework

Tags: python, robotframework, robots.txt

I am trying to store the response of built-in in a variable but I am getting **None** as a response  whats the proper way of storing value

```
    ${item} =         Page Should Contain    The login hasfailed.
    Log To Console    ${item}
```

Expected

I need the value of Page Should Contain    The login has failed.
i.e True or False is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because Page Should Contain has no return value. You can achieve your goal with Run Keyword And Ignore Error from builtin library.

```
test 
    ${result}=    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Page Should Contain    The login hasfailed.
    Log    ${result}
```

And since version 5.0 of robot framework try and except has been introduced

```
test 
    TRY
        Page Should Contain    The login hasfailed.
        Set Test Variable    ${item}    ${TRUE}
    EXCEPT
        Log    keyword failed
        Set Test Variable    ${item}    ${FALSE}
    END
    Log    ${item}
```